# Where can I find swear words?

Tags: resource-request

I have produced a series of word puzzle books for English that I want to translate into other languages. The puzzle books have challenges based on dictionaries that I have sourced from various places, and now I want to get rid of the swear words, so that the puzzles are good enough for children and teens.

I can certainly find shorter lists by doing a Google search, but is there a better place to find them?  The English language has `noswearing.com`, for example. Are there similar resources for Spanish, Portuguese (pt & br), Russian, German, French, Italian, and Danish too?

Answer (score 4):

For German I could find this giant list: http://www.hyperhero.com/de/insults.htm Despite what the page's name "insults.htm" suggests, it also contains curses, but not rather mild ones like "verdammt" (damn).

Most of these words you will never hear or read, but who knows... Naturally I could not check each word, but the words themselves are authentic, even though sometimes a bit contrived. Some of the words are also jokingly used synonyms for "wimp", for example "CD-Hüllenbenutzer", which translates to "user of CD cases".

The problem with a few of the words is ambiguity: they are by themselves harmless words that can also be used as swear words (an example for this, as in English, is "Clown") so you might have to check the German words of your puzzle books for that.

There are also widespread dialectal words that might not appear on this list, but that is an issue which likely affects also other languages.

Comment: I'd rather purge everything that is even remotely offensive than be selective.  So that list is great.  thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

There is a fairly extensive online Russian-English dictionary of swear words: http://www.russki-mat.net/e/Russian.php The words are organized in lists in alphabetical order. You can use the "letter bar" at the top of page to navigate between words starting with a specific letter. Please note, that some words have both a regular meaning and a slang meaning. For such words the explanation lists the regular meaning as "regular", or "standard Russian".

The same site also hosts French-Russian and German-Russian dictionaries of swear words in French and German respectively. The explanations are in Russian. So they won't help you, but finding a word in those dictionaries may indicate that the word needs further research.

Comment: looks like lots of editing ... to pull out the specific words ... but better than nothing.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this article](https://videnskab.dk/kultur-samfund/norge-faar-sin-foerste-bandeordbog-skal-vi-have-en-dansk), there isn't a Danish "swearing dictionary" unlike in Norwegian, so I can only point to [a limited list I found at a translation agency](https://www.dansk-og-svensk.dk/danskt_lexikon2/Bandeord/svenske_danske_bandeord.htm) for a start (right column in table on that page).

I will just add that normally Danish ones would end in -en rather than -an, but of course the meaning would be the same (dælan, hulan, sevan, ..).

And that to me "For syv" / "For syv sytten" ("For 7" / "For 7 17") are quite mild to me, as they contain no bad words and seem a bit old/comical.

Answer (score 1):

[YouSwear.com](http://www.youswear.com/) claims to have "over 200 swear languages with swears and expletives in them".

Comment: I had a look, and it looks like the start of something that could be good, but if I type on a language, I might see one or two words there.

Comment: Maybe it depends on the language, and the contributors. In Vietnamese there's a lot

Comment: I think if the site is maintained, it will grow into a really great resource.

Comment: But I'm surprised that it doesn't have enough words in the languages you are looking for. They are all popular languages

Answer (score 0):

If you know your way around a corpus, the multilingual, aligned OpenSubtiles Corpus is a good resource. Reverso Context is a nice interface and actually uses many corpora, including the one mentioned above.

For Francophones, the site expressio.fr is an  excellent resource.

Answer (score 0):

Portuguese(BR), has this list: https://aprenderpalavras.com/lista-de-palavroes-xingamentos-e-girias/

It has a pretty extensive list of words, and even regional based swears. Unfortunately, it also has name calling in it (Like *ladrão*, which is simply thief), but it should give you a pretty good base. I gave it a quick overview and it seems pretty legit.